# How can I write a heredoc to a file in Bash script?

Tags: bash, heredoc

How can I write a here document to a file in Bash script?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697688/how-to-cat-eof-a-file-containing-code-in-shell/22698106

Answer (score 1489, accepted):

Read the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide [Chapter 19. Here Documents](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

Here's an example which will write the contents to a file at `/tmp/yourfilehere`

```
cat << EOF > /tmp/yourfilehere
These contents will be written to the file.
        This line is indented.
EOF
```

Note that the final 'EOF' (The `LimitString`) should not have any whitespace in front of the word, because it means that the `LimitString` will not be recognized.

In a shell script, you may want to use indentation to make the code readable, however this can have the undesirable effect of indenting the text within your here document. In this case, use `<<-` (followed by a dash) to disable leading tabs (**Note** that to test this you will need to **replace the leading whitespace with a tab character**, since I cannot print actual tab characters here.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if true ; then
    cat <<- EOF > /tmp/yourfilehere
    The leading tab is ignored.
    EOF
fi
```

If you don't want to interpret variables in the text, then use single quotes:

```
cat << 'EOF' > /tmp/yourfilehere
The variable $FOO will not be interpreted.
EOF
```

To pipe the heredoc through a command pipeline:

```
cat <<'EOF' |  sed 's/a/b/'
foo
bar
baz
EOF
```

Output:

```
foo
bbr
bbz
```

... or to write the the heredoc to a file using `sudo`:

```
cat <<'EOF' |  sed 's/a/b/' | sudo tee /etc/config_file.conf
foo
bar
baz
EOF
```

Comment: You don't even need Bash, this feature is in the Bourne/Korn/POSIX shells too.

Comment: what about `<<<`, what are they called?

Comment: @PineappleUndertheSea `<<<` are called 'Here Strings'. Code like `tr a-z A-Z <<< 'one two three'` will result in the string `ONE TWO THREE`. More information at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings

Comment: incomplete example. What if output isn't a file but unnamed pipe to another program?

Comment: [Below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25903579/915044) I have attempted to combine and organize this answer with that of [Serge Stroobandt](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21765289/915044).

Comment: The final EOF should not have any whitespace *after* it either. At least on bash, this results in it being unrecognised as the delimiter

Comment: @carpii the final example works for me (Apple Yosemite and Bash 3.2). The final EOF is encapsulated in single quotes, and there is no whitespace after the EOF; even if there is whitespace (for readability) after the final single quote.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski Sorry, I wasn't suggesting your examples didn't work. You said "the final 'EOF' should not have any whitespace in front of the word" -- What I found on OSX 10.9 and Bash is is that a trailing space after the EOF can also cause it to fail too. I was just leaving a comment to help other people as it took me a while to figure out :)

Comment: If one doesn't want to be **forced to use tab characters** as indentation with `cat <<- EOF`, they could use `cat <<- 'EOF' | awk 'NR==1 && match($0, /^ +/){n=RLENGTH} {print substr($0, n+1)}'`. That removes the amount spaces preceding the first line in the here document from every consecutive line (see [answer by anubhava](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33837099/789308)).

Comment: Since this particular heredoc is intended to be literal content, rather than containing substitutions, it should be `<<'EOF'` rather than `<<EOF`.

Comment: You could add that `EOF` is not a special keyword, and any other limit word could be used instead. `EOF` is a meta-syntactic variable in your examples.

Comment: I'd like to add that one could set up the line `nslookup<<EOF > output.txt` equivalently to the example in the answer. The next line would be `www.google.com` followed by `exit` and then `EOF`. This was helpful to me because `nslookup` has an interactive mode and I wanted to store its output to a file.

Comment: what if you have docker-compose content in userdata pf cloudformation template? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699662/cat-eof-issues-with-indentation

Comment: Life saver, i had added a space in front of ending EOF and it wasted my half an hour

Comment: Why do I need to use 'cat' rather than 'echo'?

Comment: Recommending the ABS casts a shadow over your entire answer.

Answer (score 215):

Instead of using `cat` and I/O redirection it might be useful to use `tee` instead:

```
tee newfile <<EOF
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOF
```

It's more concise, plus unlike the redirect operator it can be combined with `sudo` if you need to write to files with root permissions.

Comment: I'd suggest adding `> /dev/null` at the end of the first line to prevent the contents of the here file being displayed to stdout when it's created.

Comment: Nice, thank you! Though that negates some of the conciseness of using `tee` in the first place I guess.

Comment: True, but your solution appealed to me because of its compatibility with `sudo`, rather than because of its brevity :-)

Comment: How would you use this method to append to an existing file?

Comment: @MountainX Check out `man tee`. Use the `-a` flag to append instead of overwrite.

Comment: For use in a config script that I sometimes need to oversee, I like this one more *because* it prints the contents.

Answer (score 82):

**Note:**

- the following condenses and organizes other answers in this thread, esp the excellent work of [Stefan Lasiewski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110223/stefan-lasiewski) and [Serge Stroobandt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2192488/serge-stroobandt)
- Lasiewski and I recommend [Ch 19 (Here Documents) in the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

The question (how to write a here document (aka *heredoc*) to a file in a bash script?) has (at least) 3 main independent dimensions or subquestions:

1. Do you want to overwrite an existing file, append to an existing file, or write to a new file?
2. Does your user or another user (e.g., `root`) own the file?
3. Do you want to write the contents of your heredoc literally, or to have bash interpret variable references inside your heredoc?

(There are other dimensions/subquestions which I don't consider important. Consider editing this answer to add them!) Here are some of the more important combinations of the dimensions of the question listed above, with various different delimiting identifiers--there's nothing sacred about `EOF`, just make sure that the string you use as your delimiting identifier does **not** occur inside your heredoc:

1. To overwrite an existing file (or write to a new file) that you own, substituting variable references inside the heredoc:

   ```
   cat << EOF > /path/to/your/file
   This line will write to the file.
   ${THIS} will also write to the file, with the variable contents substituted.
   EOF
   ```
2. To append an existing file (or write to a new file) that you own, substituting variable references inside the heredoc:

   ```
   cat << FOE >> /path/to/your/file
   This line will write to the file.
   ${THIS} will also write to the file, with the variable contents substituted.
   FOE
   ```
3. To overwrite an existing file (or write to a new file) that you own, with the literal contents of the heredoc:

   ```
   cat << 'END_OF_FILE' > /path/to/your/file
   This line will write to the file.
   ${THIS} will also write to the file, without the variable contents substituted.
   END_OF_FILE
   ```
4. To append an existing file (or write to a new file) that you own, with the literal contents of the heredoc:

   ```
   cat << 'eof' >> /path/to/your/file
   This line will write to the file.
   ${THIS} will also write to the file, without the variable contents substituted.
   eof
   ```
5. To overwrite an existing file (or write to a new file) owned by root, substituting variable references inside the heredoc:

   ```
   cat << until_it_ends | sudo tee /path/to/your/file
   This line will write to the file.
   ${THIS} will also write to the file, with the variable contents substituted.
   until_it_ends
   ```
6. To append an existing file (or write to a new file) owned by user=foo, with the literal contents of the heredoc:

   ```
   cat << 'Screw_you_Foo' | sudo -u foo tee -a /path/to/your/file
   This line will write to the file.
   ${THIS} will also write to the file, without the variable contents substituted.
   Screw_you_Foo
   ```

Comment: #6 is best. But how do you overwrite contents of existing file with #6?

Comment: @Aleksandr Makov: how do you overwrite contents of existing file with #6?

Omit the `-a` == `--append`; i.e., `tee -a` -> `tee`. See `info tee` (I'd quote it here, but comment markup is too limited.

Comment: Is there a benefit to #6 using cat and piping to tee instead of `sudo tee /path/to/your/file << 'Screw_you_Foo'`?

Comment: Why `FOE` instead of `EOF` in the append example?

Comment: @becko: just to illustrate that the label is just a label. Note that I used a different label in each example.

Answer (score 77):

To build on @Livven's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17093489/3366962), here are some useful combinations.

1. variable substitution, leading tab retained, overwrite file, echo to stdout

   ```
   tee /path/to/file <<EOF
   ${variable}
   EOF
   ```
2. **no variable substitution**, leading tab retained, overwrite file, echo to stdout

   ```
   tee /path/to/file <<'EOF'
   ${variable}
   EOF
   ```
3. variable substitution, **leading tab removed**, overwrite file, echo to stdout

   ```
   tee /path/to/file <<-EOF
       ${variable}
   EOF
   ```
4. variable substitution, leading tab retained, **append to file**, echo to stdout

   ```
   tee -a /path/to/file <<EOF
   ${variable}
   EOF
   ```
5. variable substitution, leading tab retained, overwrite file, **no echo to stdout**

   ```
   tee /path/to/file <<EOF >/dev/null
   ${variable}
   EOF
   ```
6. the above can be combined with `sudo` as well

   ```
   sudo -u USER tee /path/to/file <<EOF
   ${variable}
   EOF
   ```

Answer (score 24):

### When root permissions are required

When root permissions are required for the destination file, use `|sudo tee` instead of `>`:

```
cat << 'EOF' |sudo tee /tmp/yourprotectedfilehere
The variable $FOO will *not* be interpreted.
EOF

cat << "EOF" |sudo tee /tmp/yourprotectedfilehere
The variable $FOO *will* be interpreted.
EOF
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass variables to here documents? How could you get it so $FOO was interpreted?

Comment: [Below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25903579/915044) I have attempted to combine and organize this answer with that of [Stefan Lasiewski](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2954835/915044).

Comment: @user1527227 Just don't enclose EOF in single quotes. Then $FOO will be interpreted.

Comment: You can also use `| sudo cat >` instead of `| sudo tee` if you don't want the input to be printed back to the stdout again.  Of course, now you're using `cat` twice and doubly invoking that "unnecessary use of cat" meme, probably.

Answer (score 19):

For future people who may have this issue the following format worked:

```
(cat <<- _EOF_
        LogFile /var/log/clamd.log
        LogTime yes
        DatabaseDirectory /var/lib/clamav
        LocalSocket /tmp/clamd.socket
        TCPAddr 127.0.0.1
        SelfCheck 1020
        ScanPDF yes
        _EOF_
) > /etc/clamd.conf
```

Comment: Don't need the parentheses: `cat << END > afile` followed by the heredoc works perfectly well.

Comment: Thanks, this actually solved another issue I ran into. After a few here docs there was some issues. I think it had to do with the parens, as with the advice above it fixed it.

Comment: This won't work. The output redirection needs to be at the end of the line which starts with `cat` as shown in the accepted answer.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson It works, that's what the parens are for.  The whole `cat` runs inside a subshell, and all the output of the subshell is redirected to the file

Comment: @Izkata: If you look at the edit history of this answer, the parentheses were removed before I made my comment and added back afterwards. glenn jackman's (and my) comment applies.

Answer (score 6):

For those looking for a pure bash solution (or a need for speed), here's a simple solution without cat:

```
# here-doc tab indented
{ read -r -d '' || printf >file '%s' "$REPLY"; } <<-EOF
        foo bar
EOF
```

or for an easy "mycat" function (and avoid leaving REPLY in environment):

```
mycat() {
  local REPLY
  read -r -d '' || printf '%s' "$REPLY"
}
mycat >file <<-EOF
        foo bar
EOF
```

Quick speed comparison of "mycat" vs OS cat (1000 loops >/dev/null on my OSX laptop):

```
mycat:
real    0m1.507s
user    0m0.108s
sys     0m0.488s

OS cat:
real    0m4.082s
user    0m0.716s
sys     0m1.808s
```

NOTE: mycat doesn't handle file arguments, it just handles the problem "write a heredoc to a file"

Answer (score 3):

As instance you could use it:

**First(making ssh connection):**

```
while read pass port user ip files directs; do
    sshpass -p$pass scp -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -P $port $files $user@$ip:$directs
done <<____HERE
    PASS    PORT    USER    IP    FILES    DIRECTS
      .      .       .       .      .         .
      .      .       .       .      .         .
      .      .       .       .      .         .
    PASS    PORT    USER    IP    FILES    DIRECTS
____HERE
```

**Second(executing commands):**

```
while read pass port user ip; do
    sshpass -p$pass ssh -p $port $user@$ip <<ENDSSH1
    COMMAND 1
    .
    .
    .
    COMMAND n
ENDSSH1
done <<____HERE
    PASS    PORT    USER    IP
      .      .       .       .
      .      .       .       .
      .      .       .       .
    PASS    PORT    USER    IP    
____HERE
```

**Third(executing commands):**

```
Script=$'
#Your commands
'

while read pass port user ip; do
    sshpass -p$pass ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -p $port $user@$ip "$Script"

done <<___HERE
PASS    PORT    USER    IP
  .      .       .       .
  .      .       .       .
  .      .       .       .
PASS    PORT    USER    IP  
___HERE
```

**Forth(using variables):**

```
while read pass port user ip fileoutput; do
    sshpass -p$pass ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -p $port $user@$ip fileinput=$fileinput 'bash -s'<<ENDSSH1
    #Your command > $fileinput
    #Your command > $fileinput
ENDSSH1
done <<____HERE
    PASS    PORT    USER    IP      FILE-OUTPUT
      .      .       .       .          .
      .      .       .       .          .
      .      .       .       .          .
    PASS    PORT    USER    IP      FILE-OUTPUT
____HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the following method of basic redirection for its concision, readability and presentation in an indented script:

```
<<-End_of_file >file
→       foo bar
End_of_file
```

Where `→`        is a <kbd>tab</kbd> character.

This is standard Bourne shell redirection without forking any `cat` or `tee` process.
But it is not working with current `bash` even when called through `/bin/sh`.
It is still working with `/bin/zsh` since more than 20 years.

Comment: This does not write anything to the file

Comment: This is failing with current `bash` ( even `/bin/sh` ), but working with `zsh`. This is standard since the original Bourne shell. I was used to give this example in my course on shell to avoid stupid uses of `cat` or `tee` since the `sh` is doing it without creating a new process.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the heredoc indented for readability:

```sh
$ perl -pe 's/^\s*//' << EOF
     line 1
     line 2
EOF
```

The built-in method for supporting indented heredoc in Bash only supports leading tabs, not spaces.

Perl can be replaced with awk to save a few characters, but the Perl one is probably easier to remember if you know basic regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if you're writing to a file, it can be a good idea to check whether or not your write succeeded for failed. For example:

```
if ! echo "contents" > ./file ; then
    echo "ERROR: failed to write to file" >& 2
    exit 1
fi
```

To do the same with heredoc, there are two possible approaches.

1. ```
   if ! cat > ./file << EOF
   contents
   EOF
   then
       echo "ERROR: failed to write to file" >& 2
       exit 1
   fi
   ```
2. ```
   if ! cat > ./file ; then
       echo "ERROR: failed to write to file" >& 2
       exit 1
   fi << EOF
   contents
   EOF
   ```

You can test the error case in the above code by replacing the destination file `./file` with `/file` (assuming you're not running as `root`).