# How can I embed some HTML in a shell script?

Tags: bash, unix

I want to include some HTML in a shell script. This is what I've tried:

```
(
echo "<html> 
<head>
<title>HTML E-mail</title>
</head>
<body>
<p style="font-family:verdana;color:red;">
This text is in Verdana and red</p>
</body>
</html>"
)>pkll.htm
```

However, instead of writing the HTML to file, it gives me some errors:

```
> bash: color:red: command not found bash: > This text is in Verdana and
> red</p </body> </html>: No such file or directory
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better option would be to use the here document syntax (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2954835/761090)):

```
cat << 'EOF' > pkll.htm
<html> 
  <head>
    <title>HTML E-mail</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="font-family:verdana;color:red;">
      This text is in Verdana and red
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
EOF
```

Your attempt failed because the double quotes in the HTML terminates the double quotes you wrapped around it and causing the `<>`s to be seen as redirections and the `;`s to terminate the `echo` command.

You could technically have used single quotes:

```
( 
echo '<html> 
<head>
<title>HTML E-mail</title>
etc ...'
)>pkll.htm
```

but then you just have the same problem again if the HTML contains a `'`, such as an apostrophe or in an attribute. The here document has no such issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the quote in the html, because you have a quote on the start of the argument to echo.

Your terminal interprets it as

```
<html>...<p style="
```

first argument

```
font-family:verdana;
```

as second argument, and the rest as other commands because you have a semicolon.

So you need to replace the p tag into

```
<p style=\"font-family:verdana;color:red;\">
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide Chapter 19. Here Documents. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

```
cat << 'EOF' > pkll.htm
<html> 
<head>
<title>HTML E-mail</title>
</head>
<body>
<p style="font-family:verdana;color:red;">
This text is in Verdana and red</p>
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the online tool to do the same thing:

http://togotutor.com/code-to-html/shell-to-html.php