# do I need cat to write a heredoc to a file?

Tags: bash, cat

I've got a script that writes to a file, like so:

```
cat >myfile <<EOF
some lines
and more lines
EOF
```

but I'm not sure whether this is a Useless Use of Cat or not...

Comment: Looks perfectly fine, what do you feel is wrong with it?

Comment: Just people like to play the UUOC Superiority Card whenever possible, you don't have to be afraid of `cat`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even if this may not be a UUOC, it might be useful to use `tee` instead:

```
tee myfile <<EOF
some lines
and more lines
EOF
```

It's more concise, plus unlike the redirect operator it can be combined with `sudo` if you need to write to files with root permissions.

Comment: Doesn't this also write to standard out? In most cases this is not desired.

Comment: True – if you don't want that, add `> dev/null` to the end of the first line. See also [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953081/how-can-i-write-a-here-doc-to-a-file-in-bash-script/17093489#comment24896950_17093489).

Answer (score 2):

It is not really a UUOC.  You can also do the same with echo:

```
echo "this is line
this is another line
this is the last line" > somefile
```

Answer (score 2):

UUOC is when you use `cat` when it is not needed. As in:

```
cat file | grep "something"
```

Instead you can do it whithout cat:

```
grep "something" file
```

Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) for the original definition of UUOC.

Answer (score 2):

In zsh it is a UUOC because:

```
>myfile <<EOF
some lines
and more lines
EOF
```

Works fine.

Comment: Zsh. Chalk this up to another zsh idiosyncrasy.