# Using curl POST with variables defined in bash script functions

Tags: json, bash, curl, javascript-objects

When I echo I get this, which runs when I enter it into the terminal

```
curl -i \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-X POST --data '{"account":{"email":"akdgdtk@test.com","screenName":"akdgdtk","type":"NIKE","passwordSettings":{"password":"Starwars1","passwordConfirm":"Starwars1"}},"firstName":"Test","lastName":"User","middleName":"ObiWan","locale":"en_US","registrationSiteId":"520","receiveEmail":"false","dateOfBirth":"1984-12-25","mobileNumber":"9175555555","gender":"male","fuelActivationDate":"2010-10-22","postalCode":"10022","country":"US","city":"Beverton","state":"OR","bio":"This is a test user","jpFirstNameKana":"unsure","jpLastNameKana":"ofthis","height":"80","weight":"175","distanceUnit":"MILES","weightUnit":"POUNDS","heightUnit":"FT/INCHES"}' https://xxx:xxxxx@xxxx-www.xxxxx.com/xxxxx/xxxx/xxxx
```

But when run in the bash script file, I get this error

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application; nodename nor servname provided, or not known
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: is; nodename nor servname provided, or not known
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: a; nodename nor servname provided, or not known
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: test; nodename nor servname provided, or not known
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 158
```

this is the code in the file

```
curl -i \
-H '"'Accept: application/json'"' \
-H '"'Content-Type:application/json'"' \
-X POST --data "'"'{"account":{"email":"'$email'","screenName":"'$screenName'","type":"'$theType'","passwordSettings":{"password":"'$password'","passwordConfirm":"'$password'"}},"firstName":"'$firstName'","lastName":"'$lastName'","middleName":"'$middleName'","locale":"'$locale'","registrationSiteId":"'$registrationSiteId'","receiveEmail":"'$receiveEmail'","dateOfBirth":"'$dob'","mobileNumber":"'$mobileNumber'","gender":"'$gender'","fuelActivationDate":"'$fuelActivationDate'","postalCode":"'$postalCode'","country":"'$country'","city":"'$city'","state":"'$state'","bio":"'$bio'","jpFirstNameKana":"'$jpFirstNameKana'","jpLastNameKana":"'$jpLastNameKana'","height":"'$height'","weight":"'$weight'","distanceUnit":"MILES","weightUnit":"POUNDS","heightUnit":"FT/INCHES"}'"'" "https://xxx:xxxxx@xxxx-www.xxxxx.com/xxxxx/xxxx/xxxx"
```

I assume there's an issue with my quotation marks, but I've played with them a lot and I've gotten similar errors.  All the variables are defined with different functions in the actual script

Answer (score 390, accepted):

You don't need to pass the quotes enclosing the custom headers to curl. Also, your variables in the middle of the `data` argument should be quoted.

First, write a function that generates the post data of your script. This saves you from all sort of headaches concerning shell quoting and makes it easier to read an maintain the script than feeding the post data on curl's invocation line as in your attempt:

```
generate_post_data()
{
  cat <<EOF
{
  "account": {
    "email": "$email",
    "screenName": "$screenName",
    "type": "$theType",
    "passwordSettings": {
      "password": "$password",
      "passwordConfirm": "$password"
    }
  },
  "firstName": "$firstName",
  "lastName": "$lastName",
  "middleName": "$middleName",
  "locale": "$locale",
  "registrationSiteId": "$registrationSiteId",
  "receiveEmail": "$receiveEmail",
  "dateOfBirth": "$dob",
  "mobileNumber": "$mobileNumber",
  "gender": "$gender",
  "fuelActivationDate": "$fuelActivationDate",
  "postalCode": "$postalCode",
  "country": "$country",
  "city": "$city",
  "state": "$state",
  "bio": "$bio",
  "jpFirstNameKana": "$jpFirstNameKana",
  "jpLastNameKana": "$jpLastNameKana",
  "height": "$height",
  "weight": "$weight",
  "distanceUnit": "MILES",
  "weightUnit": "POUNDS",
  "heightUnit": "FT/INCHES"
}
EOF
}
```

It is then easy to use that function in the invocation of curl:

```
curl -i \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-X POST --data "$(generate_post_data)" "https://xxx:xxxxx@xxxx-www.xxxxx.com/xxxxx/xxxx/xxxx"
```

This said, here are a few clarifications about shell quoting rules:

The double quotes in the `-H` arguments (as in `-H "foo bar"`) tell bash to keep what's inside as a single argument (even if it contains spaces).

The single quotes in the `--data` argument (as in `--data 'foo bar'`) do the same, except they pass all text verbatim (including double quote characters and the dollar sign).

To insert a variable in the middle of a single quoted text, you have to end the single quote, then concatenate with the double quoted variable, and re-open the single quote to continue the text: `'foo bar'"$variable"'more foo'`.

Comment: "'"$<variable name>"'" solved my problem where I needed quotes to be not omitted. Thanks.

Comment: This solution works but I think you can emit the extra double quotes surrounding the variable. So instead of this: 
--data '{"account": {"email": "'"$email"'"} }'
you can do this:
--data '{"account": {"email": "'$email'"} }'

Comment: @twistedstream for properly formatted e-mail addresses, yes. If your variable contains anything naughty though (e.g. spaces), omitting the extra quotes will break your script.

Comment: how to do the same on Windows?

Comment: @dKab if you are on Windows 10, use bash and curl from the Linux Subsystem; otherwise, find one of the Windows ports for curl.

Comment: First off, thank you @SirAthos. This saved my butt. Secondly for everyone else that finds this, _make sure you include the __Content-Type:application/json___

It's easy to forget to put in, but it's necessary.

Comment: Did not work when there was a space after the second EOF: `EOF `. After removing it everything is fine.

Comment: I needed to urlencode, so this worked for me with an endpoint expecting a payload: `--data-urlencode payload="$(generate_post_data)"`

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, but where am I defining that `generate_post_data()` function?

Comment: @dbreaux That depends where you run the curl command. If the command is in a script, you simply define the function anywhere above it in that same script. If you are running curl directly from the command line, you have several options, one of which is to type up the function in a new file and then at the command line run `source my_new_file` to define the function in your current environment. After that you can run the curl command as indicated.

Comment: Please explain the cat EOF stuff

Comment: @slashdottir That's a bash feature called Here Documents. You can read about it in more detail at [this link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) - in particular, check out Example 19-5. There is also already a [full question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953081/how-can-i-write-a-heredoc-to-a-file-in-bash-script) here on SO.

Answer (score 208):

Solution tested with https://httpbin.org/ and inline bash script
**1.** For variables without spaces in it i.e. `1`:
Simply add `'` before and after `$variable` when replacing desired
string

```
for i in {1..3}; do \
  curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d \
    '{"number":"'$i'"}' "https://httpbin.org/post"; \
done
```

**2.** For input with spaces:
Wrap variable with additional `"` i.e. `"el a"`:

```
declare -a arr=("el a" "el b" "el c"); for i in "${arr[@]}"; do \
  curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d \
    '{"elem":"'"$i"'"}' "https://httpbin.org/post"; \
done
```

Comment: Does not work for when when `$i` contains spaces. :(

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: Sure. `i="a b"` instead of for-loop

Comment: I found that the accepted and the second voted answer does not work in `/bin/sh`. However, this answer did the trick. And it's much simpler than the other answers. Thank you so much! I've edited your answer with some nicer line wrapping formatting. Otherwise, it's hard to spot the brilliance. Cheers mate

Comment: Am I correct that the reason the quoting works is because the single-quotes are paired like so:
`'{"number":"'` # the first pair of single-quotes, this has the opening double-quote for json syntax.  
`$i` # bash does variable substitution.  
`'"}'` # the next pair of single-quotes, this has the closing double-quote for json syntax.

Comment: 3. for input with multi var which has spaces:`'{"text": "1.'"$var1"'\n2.'"$var2"'"}'`

Answer (score 59):

Curl can post binary data from a file so I have been using process substitution and taking advantage of file descriptors whenever I need to post something nasty with curl and still want access to the vars in the current shell. Something like:

```
curl "http://localhost:8080" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
--data @<(cat <<EOF
{
  "me": "$USER",
  "something": $(date +%s)
  }
EOF
)
```

This winds up looking like `--data @/dev/fd/<some number>` which just gets processed like a normal file. Anyway if you wanna see it work locally just run `nc -l 8080` first and in a different shell fire off the above command. You will see something like:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
Accept: application/json
Content-Type:application/json
Content-Length: 43

{  "me": "username",  "something": 1465057519  }
```

As you can see you can call subshells and whatnot as well as reference vars in the heredoc.

Comment: The other answer didn't work for me as I was trying to invoke it in an alert from Zabbix. This one solves it perfectly and is more clean.

Comment: But what if you put the code in a bash function :
myFunction () { .... }  ?

Comment: it's worth to note that this recipe works only if the script is copied verbatim (i.e. no reformatting EOF, braces etc.)

Comment: The most elegant answer I would say in terms of simplicity, readability..

Answer (score 45):

We can assign a **variable for curl** using single quote `'` and wrap **some other variables** in

- a single quote => `'` $variable `'`
- a double-quote single-quote => `"'` $variable `'"`
- a single+double+single quote => `'"'` $variable `'"'`

Lets test each case, but first watch out for this catch that if we use a single quote `'` for variable assignment, that variable is not evaluated.

#### watch out

Please notice the assignment is done by a single quote `CURL_DATA='content'`

```bash
cmd='ls'

CURL_DATA='{
    "cmd": "$cmd",    <===== our variable
    "args": [ "-la" , "/tmp" ],
    "options": {
        "cwd": "/tmp"
    },
   "type": "sync"
}';

echo "$CURL_DATA";
```

Will give us

```bash
{
    "cmd": "$cmd",    <===== we need ls not $cmd
    "args": [ "-la" , "/tmp" ],
    "options": {
        "cwd": "/tmp"
    },
   "type": "sync"
}
```

#### a single quote `'` $variable `'`

- The value of a variable is evaluated
- neither single quote `'` nor applies double one `"`

```bash
cmd='ls'

CURL_DATA='{
    "cmd": '$cmd',    <===== our variable
    "args": [ "-la" , "/tmp" ],
    "options": {
        "cwd": "/tmp"
    },
   "type": "sync"
}';

echo "$CURL_DATA";
```

Will give us:

```bash
{
    "cmd": ls,    <===== neither 'ls' nor "ls", just ls
    "args": [ "-la" , "/tmp" ],
    "options": {
        "cwd": "/tmp"
    },
   "type": "sync"
}
```

#### a double-quote single-quote `"'` $variable `'"`

- variable is evaluated
- will be surrounded by a double quote `"`

```bash
cmd='ls'

CURL_DATA='{
    "cmd": "'$cmd'",    <===== our variable
    "args": [ "-la" , "/tmp" ],
    "options": {
        "cwd": "/tmp"
    },
   "type": "sync"
}';

echo "$CURL_DATA";
```

Will give us

```bash
{
    "cmd": "ls",    <===== we have double quote " variable "
    "args": [ "-la" , "/tmp" ],
    "options": {
        "cwd": "/tmp"
    },
   "type": "sync"
}
```

#### a single+double+single quote => `'"'` $variable `'"'`

- variable is evaluated
- will be surrounded by a single quote `'`

```bash
cmd='ls'

CURL_DATA='{
    "cmd": '"'$cmd'"',
    "args": [ "-la" , "/tmp" ],
    "options": {
        "cwd": "/tmp"
    },
   "type": "sync"
}';

echo "$CURL_DATA";
```

Will give us

```bash
{
    "cmd": 'ls',    <===== we have a single quote ' variable '
    "args": [ "-la" , "/tmp" ],
    "options": {
        "cwd": "/tmp"
    },
   "type": "sync"
}
```

#### summary

```bash
# no quote at all
$cmd => $cmd

# a double quote (" $variable ")
"$cmd" => "$cmd"

# a single quote (' $variable ')
'$cmd' => ls

# a single quote + a double quote ("' $variable '")
"'$cmd'" => "ls"

# a single-double-single quote ('"' $variable '"')
'"'$cmd'"' => 'ls'
```

#### which one we should use?

Since `JSON` needs a double quote `"` for its key or value we can use :

- a double-quote single-quote `"'` $variable `'"`

#### curl

```bash
cmd='ls'

CURL_DATA='{
    "cmd": "'$cmd'",
    "args": [ "-la" , "/tmp" ],
    "options": {
        "cwd": "/tmp"
    },
   "type": "sync"
}';

echo "$CURL_DATA" | jq '.'

curl --data "$CURL_DATA" -X POST localhost:3232/cmd | jq '.'
```

---

NOTE:
The equivalent of `'` for a variable evaluation is `'"` which means instead of using `'$cmd'` we can use `'"$cmd"'` and it gives us `ls` neither with a single quote nor a double quote , but it gets more confusing if we needed to apply for **curl** since we need a double quoted result `"ls"` and would have to wrap it in another double quote => `"'"`

This code works well, but the above is more readable

```bash
cmd='ls'

CURL_DATA='{
    "cmd": "'"$cmd"'",     <===== our variable
    "args": [ "-la" , "/tmp" ],
    "options": {
        "cwd": "/tmp"
    },
   "type": "sync"
}';

echo "$CURL_DATA" | jq '.'

curl --data "$CURL_DATA" -X POST localhost:3232/cmd | jq '.'
```

Will give us:

```bash
{
    "cmd": "ls",    <===== result
    "args": [ "-la" , "/tmp" ],
    "options": {
        "cwd": "/tmp"
    },
   "type": "sync"
}
```

#### finally

We can use either of:

```bash
    "cmd": "'$cmd'",    <===== will be: "ls"
```

or

```bash
    "cmd": "'"$cmd"'",    <===== will be: "ls"
```

and `"$CURL_DATA"` as a normal variable

```bash
curl --data "$CURL_DATA" -X POST localhost:3232/cmd
```

Comment: For some reason, shell script was escaping quotes, the right combination of quotes for the placeholders did it for me.

    `some_body='{"query":"/v1/'$some_id'","body":""}'
    curl --data "$some_body" 'https://some.url'`

Comment: Pin that! 
Most correct and comprehensive answer !!!

Answer (score 13):

A few years late but this might help someone if you are using eval or backtick substitution:

```
postDataJson="{\"guid\":\"$guid\",\"auth_token\":\"$token\"}"
```

Using sed to strip quotes from beginning and end of response

```
$(curl --silent -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://${target_host}/runs/get-work -d ${postDataJson} | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')
```

Comment: simple solution, helped a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Here's what actually worked for me, after guidance from answers here:

```
export BASH_VARIABLE="[1,2,3]"
curl http://localhost:8080/path -d "$(cat <<EOF
{
  "name": $BASH_VARIABLE,
  "something": [
    "value1",
    "value2",
    "value3"
  ]
}
EOF
)" -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Answer (score 6):

the info from Sir Athos worked perfectly!!

Here's how I had to use it in my curl script for couchDB.  It really helped
out a lot.  Thanks!

```
bin/curl -X PUT "db_domain_name_:5984/_config/vhosts/$1.couchdb" -d '"/'"$1"'/"' --user "admin:*****"
```

Answer (score 5):

Existing answers point out that curl can post data from a file, and employ heredocs to avoid excessive quote escaping and clearly break the JSON out onto new lines. However there is no need to define a function or capture output from cat, because curl can post data from standard input. I find this form very readable:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' --data '$@-' ${API_URL} << EOF
{
  "account": {
    "email": "$email",
    "screenName": "$screenName",
    "type": "$theType",
    "passwordSettings": {
      "password": "$password",
      "passwordConfirm": "$password"
    }
  },
  "firstName": "$firstName",
  "lastName": "$lastName",
  "middleName": "$middleName",
  "locale": "$locale",
  "registrationSiteId": "$registrationSiteId",
  "receiveEmail": "$receiveEmail",
  "dateOfBirth": "$dob",
  "mobileNumber": "$mobileNumber",
  "gender": "$gender",
  "fuelActivationDate": "$fuelActivationDate",
  "postalCode": "$postalCode",
  "country": "$country",
  "city": "$city",
  "state": "$state",
  "bio": "$bio",
  "jpFirstNameKana": "$jpFirstNameKana",
  "jpLastNameKana": "$jpLastNameKana",
  "height": "$height",
  "weight": "$weight",
  "distanceUnit": "MILES",
  "weightUnit": "POUNDS",
  "heightUnit": "FT/INCHES"
}
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

This script will make a POST request to the specified URL with the specified JSON body, and it will output the response from the server to the console:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the URL to send the request to
url='http://example.com/endpoint'

# Set the JSON body of the request
json_data='{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}'

# Make the POST request with the JSON body
response=$(curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$json_data" "$url")

echo "Response from server: $response"
```

Comment: how to use variable in json_data tho?

Comment: @Tilo


# Set a variable
some_value='dynamic_value'

# Create the JSON body of the request with the variable
json_data='{"key1": "value1", "key2": "'"$some_value"'"}'

Comment: this worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

Putting data into a txt file worked for me

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
curl --version
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
 cat curl_data.txt 
 {  "type":"index-pattern", "excludeExportDetails": true  }

curl -X POST http://localhost:30560/api/saved_objects/_export -H 'kbn-xsrf: true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "$(cat curl_data.txt)" -o out.json
```

Comment: Of course that works, but then you have a pesky temporary file to clean up afterwards. This is only really useful on Windows, where you can't reliably interpolate variables into strings.

Answer (score 0):

[jo](https://github.com/jpmens/jo) might help:

```
$ export A=this B=that C=foo D=bar
$ jo -p a=$A b=$B nested=$(jo c=$C d=$D)
{
   "a": "this",
   "b": "that",
   "nested": {
      "c": "foo",
      "d": "bar"
   }
}
```