# Properly create CURL calls using loop in bash script

Tags: json, bash, shell, curl, devops

I need to call an API where I increment the user ID every time, I have the following in the bash script, but keep getting a `Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2` error. What am I doing wrong?

```
for ((i=1;i<=5;i++)); do
    curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "{ 'id': 'person'$i, 'name': 
    'person', 'info': {} }" 'http://localhost:9999/add'
```

Comment: learn to debug your problems with simple `echo curl -X ...... localhost:9999/add"` Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a quoting issue. It is standard for JSON to have double quotes, try this

```
for ((i=1;i<=5;i++)); do
  echo "Adding person"$i
  curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 
  'Accept: application/json' --user 'admin' -d '{ "id": "person'$i'", "name": 
  "person", "info": {} }" 'http://localhost:9999/add'
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **jq**, to ​​edit json by shellscript. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37489830/8442153).