# Curl post with JSON data fails

Tags: json, bash, curl

I'm trying to use a heredoc to pass in the ONE param I need to make a POST request via curl, this is the error I run into

```
./scripts/etcd.sh: line 10: warning: here-document at line 10 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF{peerURLs:[http://etcd-$ordinal:2380]}EOF')
./scripts/etcd.sh: line 9: warning: here-document at line 9 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF{peerURLs:[http://etcd-$ordinal:2380]}EOF')
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    42  100    42    0     0  12639      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 21000
{"message":"unexpected end of JSON input"}
```

And the 2 lines in the script that trigger it

```
request_body=$(cat <<EOF{\"peerURLs\":[\"http://etcd-$ordinal:2380\"]}EOF); 
curl http://etcd-0.etcd:2379/v2/members -XPOST -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" --data \"$request_body\";
```

I've tried all the answers here [Using curl POST with variables defined in bash script functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029902/using-curl-post-with-variables-defined-in-bash-script-functions/17032673#17032673) before asking my own question.

**Edit:**

From the answers and comments below I've tried

```
curl http://etcd-0.etcd:2379/v2/members -XPOST -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" --data @<(cat <<EOF\n{\"peerURLs\":[\"http://etcd-$ordinal:2380\"]}\nEOF)
```

And it works, but with giving a similar error

```
./scripts/etcd.sh: line 12: warning: here-document at line 10 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
./scripts/etcd.sh: line 12: warning: here-document at line 10 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
{"id":"a473da4d8f77b2b0","name":"","peerURLs":["http://etcd-3.etcd:2380"],"clientURLs":[]}
```

Comment: Here-docs don't work like this. The contents of it must start on a new line, and the end marker has to be on a line on its own. Your script thinks that the *whole thing* (`EOF{\"peerURLs\":[\"http://etcd-$ordinal:2380\"]}EOF);`) is your marker.

Comment: You don't want to escape the quotes, either. `curl -H "Content-Type..." --data "$request_body"`.

Comment: Consider using a tool like `jq` to generate your JSON, especially when you are embedding the contents of a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
request_body="{\"peerURLs\":[\"http://etcd-$ordinal:2380\"]}"
```

[Here-docs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument) (`<<EOF\n ... \nEOF`):

- are inherently *multi-line* constructs (because yours isn't, you're getting the warning)
- send their contents to *stdin*.

Neither aspect is required in your case, where a single-line, expandable string (`"..."`) is sufficient.

Additionally, the way you use quoting in your `curl` command is broken - see bottom.

---

If you did want to **use a here-doc with a variable**, this is the most efficient idiom:

```
read -d '' -r request_body <<EOF
{"peerURLs":["http://etcd-$ordinal:2380"]}
EOF
```

<sup>**Note**: The **closing delimiter**, `EOF` here, must be **on its own line**, **at the very start** of the line (no leading whitespace allowed),
 and **no other characters may follow**, not even whitespace and comments.</sup>

`read` is used to read the here-doc's contents, via stdin (`-d ''` ensures that the entire here-doc is read as a whole, and `-r` is used to ensure that the content is read without interpretation of embedded `\` chars.)

As you can see, the advantage here is that there's no need to escape embedded `"` chars. as `\"`.

---

[chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) points out that often you can **use here-docs *directly***, without the need for an auxiliary variable; in this case, `@-` as the `--data` argument tells `curl` to read from stdin:

```
curl http://etcd-0.etcd:2379/v2/members -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data @- <<EOF
{"peerURLs":["http://etcd-$ordinal:2380"]}
EOF
```

The above command also shows how to quote the `-H` option-argument correctly: using unescaped single-quoting to produce a string *literal*. By contrast, `\"Content-Type: application/json\"` would create *2* arguments, `"Content-Type:`and `application/json"` - with `\"` turning into *embedded* `"` chars.

Similarly, to use your `$request_body` variable instead of a here-doc, use `"$request_body"` rather than `\"$request_body\"`.

Comment: @Jonathan: It sounds like you're seeing an unrelated error. If you use the here-doc as posted in this answer with `bash`, it should work. Also note that, as chepner has already pointed out, your `curl` command is broken with respect to quoting - see my update.

Comment: My  quoting use is needed, because I'm writing bash commands to a file with cat, within a kubernetes yaml file annotation where the whole block is surrounded by double quotes already, other than thatI agree with you that I'm still very very unfamiliar with heredocs :)

Comment: @Jonathan: I see - you should have mentioned that in your question to avoid confusion.