# curl: 400 Bad Request. The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: shell, curl

I'm getting "400 Bad Request. The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand." for the curl command. Curl command is as below, can someone please help?

```
token=jfkdjfdikdjydve83hhd54rsfdghsghktwhdh87
payload_file=test_fortify_scan.zip

curl -X POST https://dnsname/api/scan \
-H "authorization: Bearer $token" \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
-d '{"projVer": "dev", "language": "java", 
"payloadFile":"$payload_file", "emailList": "myemail@mail.com"}'
```

Comment: I really like how prettily you laid out the `curl` command across multiple lines like that. I just copied that style.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like quotes problem. Look at [Using curl POST with variables defined in bash script functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029902/using-curl-post-with-variables-defined-in-bash-script-functions)

```
token="jfkdjfdikdjydve83hhd54rsfdghsghktwhdh87"
payload_file="test_fortify_scan.zip"

curl -X POST https://dnsname/api/scan \
-H "authorization: Bearer $token" \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
-d '{"projVer": "dev", "language": "java",
"payloadFile":"'"$payload_file"'", "emailList": "myemail@mail.com"}'
```

Comment: thanks for the response. yes, it was quotes problem and same has been fixed now.