# How to print some text exactly in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

How do I print some text (in this case another bash script) exactly to some output file in bash?

So essentially I want to do something equivalent to the following but with special conditions:

```
echo [some multiline bash script] > output.bash
```

and output.bash would contain [some multiline bash script] exactly and no variable substitution occur

Comment: Have a look at [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2953081/205936).

Comment: Also, you don't want variable interpolation to occur, you can quote the 'Limit String' as shown [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html). Look for 'Parameter substitution turned off' or just copy the entire script into `output.bash`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat [some multiline bash script] > output.bash
```

Answer (score 0):

print some text to file.name

```
cat >> file.name <<EOF
# base script 
ls
ls
cd ..
#...
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

use single quote ''

like this '\' is for multi line input

```
#oyss=2
#echo '$oyss \
> $oyss line 2
> ' > 1.txt

#cat 1.txt
$oyss\
$oyss line 2
```

if you use double quote "".you will get the variable evaluated.

```
#echo "$oyss\
> $oyss line 2
> "
22 line 2
```