# Is it possible to pass a list of numbers as argument using <?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, stdin

I was wondering how would you pass and then retrieve a list of numbers to a script using this syntax:

```
python3 program.py < 1 2 3 4
```

I know I can pass arguments using the following syntax:

```
python3 program.py 1 2 3 4
```

And then retrieve the arguments using `sys.argv`:

```
print(sys.argv)  # a list of arguments
```

I have seen around, but for some reason I was not able to do it.

Note that I am wondering if it's possible or not, I am not asking ways to read from the standard input that are different from my first example above.

Comment: Well then, I'll leave it here. Just note that `sys.stdin` is used to read from the standard input an when redirected it read's from the mentioned input

Comment: If you had a simple utility that did nothing but echo its command line arguments to stdout, you could do something like;`util 1 2 3 4 > python3 program.py`

Comment: @martineau do you mean `util 1 2 3 4 | python3 program.py`?

Comment: @Zero: Yes, that's what I should have written.

Comment: Taking a cue from @martineau `echo 1 2 3 4 | python test.py` would send a string `"1 2 3 4"` to the python program in which you can split based on space and map each to a set of numbers.

Comment: Some unix shells allow something called a "here document" or "inline file" using `<<` — see [_How can I write a here doc to a file in Bash script?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953081/how-can-i-write-a-here-doc-to-a-file-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 2):

You've misunderstood the syntax of your proposed command.

Here's a simple python program that prints out the contents of standard input and command-line arguments:

```
# program.py

import sys

print("stdin:", sys.stdin.read())
print("args:", sys.argv)
```

... and here's what happens when you call it with your proposed syntax:

```
$ python3 program.py < 1 2 3 4
stdin: This is the content of file '1'.

args: ['program.py', '2', '3', '4']
```

In other words, your syntax redirects the content of a file '1' to standard input, and supplies the arguments '2', '3' and '4' to the program.

So, **no**, what you want to do isn't possible - not because of Python, but because of the way the shell works.

Comment: Yep, Zero you have struck the right chord +1, That is what I am trying to explain to the OP.

Comment: Is it possible to escape `<` ?

Comment: @User: yes, e.g., in bash `'<'` (just surround it by quotes): `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1:])' '<' 1 2 3`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass a list of numbers using redirection. There is [here-string syntax in bash](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection#here_strings):

```
$ python3 -c 'print(sum(map(int, input().split())))' <<<'1 2 3'
6
```

Though it is more straightforward to pass it as an argument list:

```
$ python -c 'import sys; print(sum(map(int, sys.argv[1:])))' 1 2 3
6
```

`< 1` tries to redirect stdin from the file named `1`. It is probably *not* what you want.

Comment: Terrific idea of using `>>>` ! I broke my head and finally came up with a poor version [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175282/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-list-of-numbers-as-argument-using/29175443#comment46569254_29175282). I guess this is it (what the OP wants)