# What does this error mean? (SC2129: Consider using { cmd1; cmd2; } >> file instead of individual redirects.)

Tags: bash, shell, shellcheck

I'm writing a script to generate draft posts for my blog. After running [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net), I keep seeing this error pop up. What does this mean and can someone provide an example?

> `SC2129: Consider using { cmd1; cmd2; } >> file instead of individual redirects.`

In addition, I'm not sure what I need to do in order to pass the value of `$title` to the `"Title"` field in the post's YAML...

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set some variables

var site_path=~/Documents/Blog
drafts_path=~/Documents/Blog/_drafts
title="$title"

# Create the filename

title=$("$title" | "awk {print tolower($0)}")
filename="$title.markdown"
file_path="$drafts_path/$filename"
echo "File path: $file_path"

# Create the file, Add metadata fields

echo "---" > "$file_path"
{
    echo "title: \"$title\""
}   >> "$file_path"

echo "layout: post" >> "$file_path"
echo "tags: " >> "$file_path"
echo "---" >> "$file_path"

# Open the file in BBEdit

bbedit "$file_path"

exit 0
```

Comment: `{echo 'foo'; echo 'bar'; echo 'baz'; } >> file` instead of separate/repeated `echo x >> file`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you click in the message given by shellcheck, you will arrive to https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2129

There you can find the following:

> **Problematic code:**
>
> ```
> echo foo >> file
> date >> file
> cat stuff  >> file
> ```
>
> **Correct code:**
>
> ```
> { 
>   echo foo
>   date
>   cat stuff
> } >> file
> ```
>
> **Rationale:**
>
> Rather than adding >> something after every single line, you can
>   simply group the relevant commands and redirect the group.
>
> **Exceptions**
>
> This is mainly a stylistic issue, and can freely be ignored.

So basically replace:

```
echo "---" > "$file_path"
{
    echo "title: \"$title\""
}   >> "$file_path"

echo "layout: post" >> "$file_path"
echo "tags: " >> "$file_path"
echo "---" >> "$file_path"
```

With:

```
{
    echo "---"
    echo "title: \"$title\""
    echo "layout: post"
    echo "tags: "
    echo "---"
}   > "$file_path"
```

Even though I would suggest you to use a [heredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2954835/1983854):

```
cat >"$file_path" <<EOL
---
title: "$title"
layout: post
tags: 
---
EOL
```

Comment: The first version opens and closes the file several times. The second opens and closes it just once. It doesn't matter much, but it's something to consider.