# Why so many `err:` prefixes in the output of ssh-action even if everything is fine?

Tags: bash, ssh, github-actions

I am on [appleboy/ssh-action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/ssh-remote-commands) and I have a very simple step built on it

```
steps:
  - name: execute remote commands
    uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
    with:
      host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
      username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
      key: ${{ secrets.KEY }}
      port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
      script: |
        echo "Go to the project space"
        cd $HOME/actions_workspace/actions-sample
        echo "Pulling the repo from the remote server"
        git pull origin main
        echo "Building the new container"
        docker-compose build
```

It works fine, but this is the output:

```
======CMD======
echo "Go to the project space"
cd $HOME/actions_workspace/actions-sample
echo "Pulling the repo from the remote server"
git pull origin main
echo "Building the new container"
docker-compose build

======END======
out: Go to the project space
out: Pulling the repo from the remote server
err: From github.com:floatingpurr/my-test-repo
err:  * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
err:    3961b2c..26e6abe  main       -> origin/main
out: Updating 3961b2c..26e6abe
out: Fast-forward
out:  README.md          |  2 +-
out:  docker-compose.yml | 12 ++++++------
out:  2 files changed, 7 insertions(+), 7 deletions(-)
out: Building the new container
err: my-test-actions uses an image, skipping
==============================================
✅ Successfully executed commands to all host.
==============================================
```

I'm just wondering the reason why I see `err:` prefixes in the action output and not just `out:` (as I would have expected) since everything went fine.

Comment: I suspect that means that `git` is printing those messages to `stderr` rather than `stdout`.

Comment: Oh, really? Looks like the same is for `docker-compose`... is it "normal"?

Comment: See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331611/do-progress-reports-logging-information-belong-on-stderr-or-stdout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37561629/6309), any informative messages, not to be consumed by machines, is to be routed to stderr.
As [illustrated here](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Bugreport-Git-responds-with-stderr-instead-of-stdout-tp4959280p4959530.html)

> Verbose status and progress reports, especially human readable
> ones, should probably always go to stderr.

If you really need to, you could [redirect stderr to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57016167/6309), but that is not needed here.

Comment: Thanx for pointing this out. This behavior doesn't affect exit codes, I guess...

Comment: @floatingpurr No it does not.