# How to store multiline sql query in a shell variable?

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, shell

How can i hold multiline sql query in a shell variable?

```
SQL='Lets get CREATE TRIGGER STATEMENT'
```

How to hold it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I write a here doc to a file in Bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953081/how-can-i-write-a-here-doc-to-a-file-in-bash-script)

Comment: Dear @AvinashRaj did you read my title ?

Comment: Myfriend take a look at http://ideone.com/C5JI6d

Comment: I need it without creating a file

Comment: `newfile` is just a variable name.

Comment: It will create a file inside current directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82777/discussion-between-underscore-and-avinash-raj).

Comment: This is related to MySQL — see the chat (and the newly added tag).  The problem was related to the DELIMITER statement within a sequence of SQL statements being passed to the `mysql` program.  Changing the delimiter from `//` to `|` seems to fix it; there's no clear explanation of why as yet.

Answer (score 1):

This worked well for me

```
  extract_sql="SELECT *
               FROM TABLE"
```

To run SQLs with command line tools like wxsubmit or sqlplus

```
 commandlinesqltool  -options << EOF > /dev/null 2>&1

    SET HEADER OFF

    UPDATE TABLE
    SET    A=1;

EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(max);

SET @sql='SELECT *'+char(13) +'FROM table'

Print(@sql);


result: SELECT *
        FROM table
```

In above query char(13) will hepls to write in next line.

Now @sql variable has two lines.

Comment: Are you confusing MySQL with SQL Server?  Though I see that the question isn't tagged MySQL, but the chat feeds the SQL to the `mysql` program.