# EOFError when executing Python scripts in I/O Redirection

Tags: python, linux, unix

If I make a program "prog.py" in Python with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.3
# -*-coding:Utf-8 -*

while True:
    number = int(input())
    print(number * 2)
```

I have a file "numbers.txt" with that:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

And I run it like that:

```
chmod +x prog.py
cat numbers.txt | ./prog.py
```

I get that:

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 5, in <module>
    number = int(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Why this error?

Comment: What's a extra enter?

Comment: Chek http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953081/how-can-i-write-a-here-doc-to-a-file-in-bash-script
´files =  [e.rstrip for e in (open(numbers.txt).readlines())]#a list´
Every print is new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected; you try to read from standard input with `input` without checking if you've reached the end of the file. However, it's better practice to iterate directly over the file `sys.stdin` than to repeatedly call `input`.

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    number = int(line)
    print(number * 2)
```

The iteration will stop automatically when you reach the end of the file, so there's no need to check for it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using

```
while True:
```

Replace it with

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    number = int(line.strip())
```