# Pass values read from a file as input to an SQL query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, bash, unix, sqlplus

```
#cat file.txt
 12354
 13456
 13498
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat file.txt`
do
    sqlplus XXXXX/XXXXX@DB_NAME << EOF 
        select *from TABLE_NAME where id="$i"
    EOF
done
```

---

This is not working for me. Help me how I can solve this.

Comment: You didn't tell what error you are getting.  I guess it is because of "EOF" being indented.

Comment: You could also change your select to use 'in' and store the data in an array.  Also, if you place a hyphen before EOF you can use it indented (must be by tabs only)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the right way to use the heredoc `<<`, along with the choice of `while read` instead of `for` to read the file:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r value; do
  sqlplus xxxxx/xxxxx@db_name << EOF
    select * from table_name where id='$value';
    # make sure heredoc marker "EOF" is not indented
EOF
done < file.txt
```

---

See also:

- [How can I write a here doc to a file in Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953081/how-can-i-write-a-here-doc-to-a-file-in-bash-script)
- [BashFAQ001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) to understand why `for` loop is not the best way to read text lines from a file.

Comment: Problem was indentation..!

Answer (score 2):

The solution given by @codeforester works. However I was unable to use it because it created as many DB connections as the number of lines in your file which is a potential impact.

To overcome this, I chose the below solution which may not be ideal but does the job with just one DB connection.

Considering the same data in file.txt

```
 12354
 13456
 13498
```

I used the below sed command to populate the above to a single variable "12354,13456,13498"

```
myvariable=$(echo "`cat file.txt | sed '$!s/$/,/g' | tr -d '\n' | tr -d ' '`")
```

Now below script will pass this variable to the SQL query and spool the data into a text file:

```
#!/bin/bash
myvariable=$(echo "`cat file.txt | sed '$!s/$/,/g' | tr -d '\n' | tr -d ' '`")
echo @myvariable
sqlplus /nolog << EOF
CONNECT user@dbname/dbpassword
SPOOL dboutput.txt
select column1 from table_name where id in ($myvariable);
SPOOL OFF
EOF
```

The output is stored in dboutput.txt  (along with the SQL query)

```
cat dboutput.txt
SQL>   select column1 from table_name where id in (12354,13456,13498);

NAME
----------------------------------------------------------------------------  ----
data1
data2
data3

SQL> spool off
```