# How to execute a psql command within a bash for loop

Tags: bash, loops

I want to execute a psql statement within a bash script and output the results to a file. The code I have below works as desired:

```
#!/bin/bash

query="select * from mytable;"

psql <<EOF > output.txt
\timing
$query
EOF
```

I want to run that psql command block 5 times and have the results appended to `output.txt`. It works fine if I just copy and paste it an additional 4 times, but when I try to put it inside of a for-loop, I get errors. Is there any way to do this?

This is the loop I tired:

```
#!/bin/bash

query="select * from mytable;"

for (( i=0; i<5; i++ ))
do
   psql <<EOF > output.txt
   \timing
   $query
   EOF
done
```

If I move the final `EOF` all the way over to the left, it only executes once, as if the loop wasn't there.

Comment: Replace `> output.txt` with `>> output.txt`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overwriting the file each time with `>` inside the loop.  You need `>>` inside or have `>` outside the loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

query="select * from mytable;"
for (( i=0; i<5; i++ ))
do
   psql <<EOF
   \timing
   $query
EOF
done > output.txt
```

Putting `>` after `done` is a little more efficient than `>>` inside the loop.

---

Similar post:

- [Pass values read from a file as input to an SQL query in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42407325/pass-values-read-from-a-file-as-input-to-an-sql-query-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

It is usually  better to not run Postgres in a loop. Just generate the commands you want to execute, then run the sequence of generated commands once.

```
#!/bin/bash

query="select * from mytable;"

for (( i=0; i<5; i++ ))
do
   cat <<___EOF
   \timing
   $query
___EOF
done |
psql > output.txt
```

which of course in this case can be simplified to just

```
#!/bin/bash
printf '-- %s\n\\timing\nselect * from mytable;\n' {1..5} |
psql >output.txt
```

The brace expansion `{1..5}` is Bash-specific, so you can't use `sh` for this particular snippet. ([There is a difference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash))