# Need to read and write to excel sheet from database

Tags: excel, oracle, plsql

I have an excel spreadsheet with the first column full of Phone numbers.
I want to check these numbers with my database so that when they exist in my database, I need to get the name (found in the database) corresponding to every Phone number I have. Preferably if I can add it directly next to the number in the excel sheet

I'm using SQL plus 8.0

Comment: Show the code you've done so far, and what exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: I haven't done anything, I don't know where to start / what to use

Comment: Try to start with his one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42407325/pass-values-read-from-a-file-as-input-to-an-sql-query-in-oracle

Comment: Which version of the **database** (not the SQL\*Plus client) are you using? Does it have to be Excel format or can you convert the input to text (CSV format)? Is this a one-off exercise or a recurring task? Do you have access to improved clients (such as Oracle SQL Developer)? Can you install third party PL/SQL packages in your database?

Comment: Sounds like instead of driving the process from the database you should drive it from the Excel worksheet.  Excel can query Oracle via odbc.

Comment: Oracle8i Release 8.1.7.0.0
it is a recurring task, what kind of third parties are you suggesting? @APC

Comment: @EdStevens can you elaborate how i can do that?

Comment: You don't need to worry about third party libraries: you're running an unpatched version of the database which has been obsolete for two decades, so there probably isn't anything out there which will work for you. I agree with @EdStevens that ODBC is the best approach. The tricky point will be drivers. If your version of Microsoft is as archaic as your Oracle then you might be alright. Otherwise you may struggle to find compatible versions of ODBC. [This article is a good jumping off point](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2011/11/13/excel-oracle-odbc-driver/) because it has useful links..

Comment: I haven't done it myself in quite some time, so can't describe it off the top of my head. However, a few minutes with google "connect excel to oracle via odbc" should turn up lots of help.  Your problem will be that your db, at v8, is a museum piece.