# Shell script to update sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, shell

I'm on FreeBSD11. I have one or more zfs pool on my system. I want a script to check pool status and update the database, my code is:

```
pool=$(/sbin/zpool status | grep pool |awk '{print $2}')
for i in $pool
do

    status=$(/sbin/zpool status ${i} | egrep -i '(ONLINE|DEGRADED|FAULTED|OFFLINE|UNAVAIL|REMOVED|FAIL|DESTROYED|corrupt|cannot|unrecover)')

    sqlite3 <address>/my.db <<EOS
            update myTable set status = $status where name = ${i};

    EOS

    echo $status
   done
```

This code has error, and doesn't update my database. Can you help me figure out the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues in your code:

1. The heredoc marker "EOF" should not be indented
2. You need single quotes in your SQL

Rewrite it as:

```
    sqlite3 <address>/my.db <<EOS
            update myTable set status = '$status' where name = '$i';
EOS
```

---

See also:

- [How can I write a here doc to a file in Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953081/how-can-i-write-a-here-doc-to-a-file-in-bash-script)

Comment: thank you for your reply, actually I searched about sqlite in shell script and found that code in stackoverflow. Now I replce the code with your answer, it has error`Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "done")`,. I placed `done` at the end of the code.

Comment: This is my correct code: `#!/bin/sh
pool=$(/sbin/zpool status | grep pool |awk '{print $2}')
for i in $pool
do
        status=$(/sbin/zpool status ${i} |grep state|awk '{print $2}')


        echo 'update myTble set status =  '\'''$status''\'';'|sqlite3  <address>mydb.db

done`