# Bash enters both if and else statements

Tags: bash

Here is the context: I'm making a small Linux command for me to automatically create the base code when I create a C program.
The name of my command is `ctouch`: it's like the `touch` command but after creating the file(s) it also creates the basic structure of a C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){



    return 0:
}
```

Appending these lines works. Here is my code:

```
#! /bin/bash

for arg in "$@"
do
    [ ${arg: -2} == ".c" ] && touch "$arg" || touch "$arg.c"

    echo '#include <stdio.h>' > "$arg"
    echo '#include <stdlib.h>' >> "$arg"
    echo $'\nint main90{\n\n\t' >> "$arg"
    echo $'\n\treturn 0;\n\n}' >> "$arg"
done
```

As you see, it can create as much files as `touch` can take arguments. The conditional loop (the line after the `do`) is useful in case I forgot to specify the `.c` extension: but the problem is that both `if` and `else` are executed when the argument does not end in `.c` But it's ok when I don't "forget" to specify that it is a C file.

How can I fix that?

Comment: If `$arg` doesn't contain a `.c` you create a file named `$arg.c`. Later on in your script you write to `$arg`, but we just established that `$arg` doesn't contain a `.c` so you are writing to the non-`.c` file with that redirect. I suspect this script works fine when your `$arg` contains `.c` though.

Comment: Notice that `condition && cmd1 || cmd2` is not exactly equivalent to `if condition then cmd1; else cmd2; fi` – if `cmd1` fails, `cmd2` will be executed! (See [Bash Pitfall 22](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3))

Comment: You can trade one `bash`ism for another, clearer one: `if [[ $arg == *.c ]]; then touch "$arg"; else touch "$arg.c"`.

Comment: You can also dispense with the test altogether, with a POSIX-compatible parameter expansion at that: `arg=${arg%.c}.c`. This strip `.c` if present, then puts it back whether it was there in the first place or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't taking both branches. It does the `touch` depending on the extension, but then the `echo` sequence places its output in the file without an extension if that's what you passed in.

I would refactor to use `case`, use a [here document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953081/how-can-i-write-a-heredoc-to-a-file-in-bash-script) to print multiple lines, and skip the `touch` entirely; but the minimal fix is just to change the output file name if it lacks the extension.

```
for arg in "$@"
do
    case $arg in
      *.c) ;;
      *) arg="$arg.c";;
    esac

    cat <<'____HERE' > "$arg"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){




    return 0;
}
____HERE
done
```

With these changes, the code should also be portable to POSIX `/bin/sh`.

Comment: probably because heredocs are easier to read and to write (and change).

Comment: Actually I used `printf` rather than a heredoc, but someone thought they could "improve" my answer. Either way, `echo` has some pesky portability problems; both `printf` and `cat` a here document avoid those elegantly.

Comment: The `printf` answer I originally posted made tabs etc explicit; but a here document with tabs in the right places will work fine too (just not show symbolically where the tabs go), so I'll leave the edit by @JohnKugelman.

Answer (score 1):

A little alteration:

```
#! /bin/bash

for arg in "$@"
do
     [[ ${arg: -2} == ".c" ]] && FILE="$arg" || FILE="$arg.c"
    echo '#include <stdio.h>' > "$FILE"
    echo '#include <stdlib.h>' >> "$FILE"
    echo $'\nint main90{\n\n\t' >> "$FILE"
    echo $'\n\treturn 0;\n\n}' >> "$FILE"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

A simplified solution avoids any need for a conditional. You want to create a `.c` file whether or not the original argument ends with `.c`, effectively adding it if it isn't already there. This is the same as *always* adding it to the result of *trying* to remove it. You also don't need to explicitly create the file with `touch`; output redirection will create the file if necessary.

This also demonstrates Yet Another Way to write the contents of your template to a file.

```
for arg in "$@"
do
  {
    printf '#include <stdio.h>\n'
    printf '#include <stdlib.h>\n'
    printf '\nint main90 {\n'
    printf '\n\treturn 0;\n\n}\n'  # end with a newline
  } > "${arg%.c}.c"
done
```

Note that your file should probably be a proper POSIX text file, ending with a newline character.

Comment: My original answer had a single `printf` so you could do away with the braces, too. (This is more elegant than the blind copy/paste of the OP's code that I had, though.)

Comment: I toyed with that, but it gets ugly unless you use an array of lines, in which case you might as well just accept the cost of running `cat` with an here document like you used.

Answer (score 0):

alternative with here document:

```
for arg in "$@"; do
    if [ "${arg: -2}" == ".c" ]; then
        filename="$arg"
    else
        filename="${arg}.c"
    fi

cat<<EOT >"$filename"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {


    return 0;
}
EOT

done
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Can you explain what does this cat EOF... etc, mean? Or can you give me a link that explain it?