# Is there an equivalent to tee that doesn’t output to stdout?

Tags: shell

Currently using the following and would like to remove the `> /dev/null` part.

```
cat << "EOF" | sudo tee /etc/pf.conf > /dev/null
EOF
```

For reference, the following throws an error.

> zsh: permission denied: /etc/pf.anchors/local.test

```sh
sudo cat << "EOF" > /etc/pf.anchors/local.test
echo "Hello world"
EOF
```

Comment: What is point of using `tee` here?

Comment: @anubhava Writing to this file requires root privileges so `> /etc/pf.conf` doesn’t work.

Comment: @anubhava That’s what I tried first. It threw a permission error. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2954835/4579271

Comment: @anubhava Please see updated question. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: None as far as I'm concerned. Run the whole command in a root shell (i.e after running `sudo -s`, or `sudo bash -c 'your script here'`)

Comment: @anubhava, `sudo cat` has no advantage there since opening `/etc/pf.conf` is done by the shell before either `sudo` or `cat` is started, so it doesn't benefit from any privileges escalation.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy. I stand corrected.

Comment: I don't see why you'd want to avoid using `tee`. Redirecting its standard output isn't that onerous.

Comment: Also, useless use of `cat`: `sudo tee /etcpf.conf > /dev/null <<EOF`

Answer (score 1):

You can start a new shell with root rights and redirect inside it:

```
sudo sh -c 'cat > "$1"' -- /etc/pf.conf
```

or shorter:

```
sudo sh -c 'cat > "$0"' /etc/pf.conf
sudo sh -c 'cat>"$0"' /etc/pf.conf
```

Use `awk` with redirection:

```
sudo awk -vf=/etc/pf.conf '{print > f}'
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting an answer. Can you please include the heredoc in your example? I don’t understand...

Comment: What do you mean? You mean why does it fail with permission denied when you just do `sudo cat > file`?

Comment: I am trying to write a one-liner that outputs the content of an elaborate (simplified in the question) heredoc to `/etc/pf.conf` using sudo.

Comment: Just `sudo tee /etc/pf.conf >/dev/null <<EOF`. No need for `cat`.

Comment: @sunknudsen, ...*why* do you object to the `>/dev/null`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don’t, just curious to know if there is a cleaner way to write this line. I tend to learn a lot from you guys. Often there are much more elegant ways of writing this stuff that what I can come up with.

Comment: Then I think the consensus is to stick to `tee >/dev/null`.