# sqlite dot commands variable expansion like bash

Tags: bash, sqlite, variables

I have a loop in bash that sets some pathnames as variables.

Within that loop I want to perform some sqlite commands based on these variables.

for example:

```sh
sqlitedb="/Users/Documents/database.db"
for mm in 01 02 03; do
filename1="A:/data1-${mm}.csv"
filename2="D:/data2-${mm}.csv"
sqlite3 "$sqlitedb" #create new file, it is a temporary file.  no problem with this command.
.mode csv
.import "$filename1" data_1 #try to import the first data file.  This command doesn't work
.import "$filename2" data_2 #try to import the second data file.  This command doesn't work
# now do some important sql stuff which joins these files.
.quit
rm -f "$sqlitedb" #remove old file, ready for the next loop
done
```

Clearly, SQLITE doesn't know about my BASH variables.  What is the best way to set variables, loop through files, etc within sqlite3?

If it helps, I'm using  WSL ubuntu 18.04

Comment: This will not work as written, because `sqlite3` will read its commands from standard input (generally the Terminal) rather than the script file. You'd need something like a [here-document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953081/how-can-i-write-a-heredoc-to-a-file-in-bash-script) to give input to the `sqlite3` command, and shell variables *are* substituted in here-documents (unless the delimiter is quoted). Please post a [minimal example that actually shows the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a heredoc, as mentioned in comments:

```
for mm in 01 02 03; do
    filename1="A:/data1-${mm}.csv"
    filename2="D:/data2-${mm}.csv"
    sqlite3 -batch -csv <<EOF
.import "$filename1" data_1
.import "$filename2" data_2
-- Do stuff with the tables
EOF
done
```

(If you leave off a filename, sqlite uses a in-memory database so you don't need a manual temporary database file unless you have a lot of data to store)

Comment: checked and works perftecly.  I was not aware of the `-batch` switch, but it seems just what I need. 
I still don't understand why the variable expansion works, even in the heredoc; the `.import` command is part of sqlite3 interpreter, so I didn't expect it to be aware of shell variables.  Is it because interactive mode is switched off via the `-batch` switch?